# Displaying a history of uploaded images

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview

So I have an app that uploads multiple photos with an HTTP 'POST' request in Objective-C and it works fine. But what I am trying to do is display all the images uploaded from that specific device in a table like a "Upload History" section. I was wondering how to get the image URL of every image the device posts, if it would be better to save the image URL to an NSDictionary or an SQLite table and how to display the all the images into the table. This is an example of uploading one image with a single parameter I have, but how do I get the image URL to return to me and save it so I can display all uploaded images to a table?

```
 [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: attachment; name=\"uploaded_file\"; filename=\"%@.png\"\r\n", dateString] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imagePNG]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"ticket\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[ticketNumber.text dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


        [request setHTTPBody:body];
```

Comment: I would advice to add some code with your question in hopes to have someone help you.

Comment: My main concern is how to get the image url back and putting it into some sort of database, if anyone can help me with that, that would be great.

Comment: I was doing it wrong the whole time my other question is how I was supposed to be doing it :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you successfully upload those images, the server should return you two things

1. Http status code 201: This means that a resource has been created on the server.
2. The path of the newly created resources in an array.

So your JSON response for the image upload service may look something like this

```
    {
  "imagePath": [
    "https://yourServer/img/img1.png"
    "https://yourServer/img/img2.png",
    "https://yourServer/img/img3.png"
  ],
}
```

You can store these paths inside a sqlite database and retrieve those URL when you load your view, but the problem with this approach is that you have to be updated i.e. if someone updates any image on the server then your database also needs to be in sync with that.

The less painful path could is to call a new service which returns the list of image URLs stored on the server folder, this way you can lazy load them in the table view using [SDWebImage](https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage) or any other pod you like.